# How to prove whether following inequality holds

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Assuming $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, how to prove or disprove this inequality?
$$ 2a \left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil - b 
{\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil}^2 \geq \frac{a^2}{b} $$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$2ax - bx^2 \le \frac{a^2}{b}$$
$$2abx - (bx)^2 \le a^2$$
$$0 \le a^2 - 2abx + (bx)^2 = (a - bx)^2$$

Comment: when $x=a/b\in\mathbb{N}$ the equal sign holds and the original OP inequality holds